# Format Text Within color_bar {formattable}

Tags: r, kable, formattable

I am formatting a table using formattable:color_bar and would like to add a comma as a thousands separator as well as adjust the colour of the font.

For cells where I don't use color_bar I see how I can use cell_spec to change the font color but I don't know how to do it with cells that are using color_bar.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

df <- tibble (
  rank = c(1,2,3),
  tree = c("Norway Maple", "Honey Locust", "Colorado Blue Spruce"),
  number = c(74688, 24286, 21917)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    tree = cell_spec(tree, "html", color = "black"),
    number = color_bar()(number)) %>% 

  kable("html", escape = F,  align = c("l", "l")) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover", "responsive", "condensed"), full_width = F, position = "float_left")  %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "10cm")
```